# ModelSim unexpected z input

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm building a simple 7-segment display.
I didn't have errors when I was compiling the module and testbench.
But, when I'm simulating, I keep getting `z` value as input.  Why do I get the `z`?

Verilog code as below :

```
module  dec_7seg(d, seg);

input [3:0]d;
output [7:0]seg;

assign seg[1]= (d[1]&~d[2]) | d[0] | (~d[1]&d[2]) | (d[2]&~d[3]);
assign seg[2]= (~d[0]&d[1]) | (~d[1]&~d[2]&~d[3]) | (d[1]&d[2]) | (d[0]&~d[1]&d[3]);
assign seg[3]= (~d[1]&~d[3]) | (d[0]&d[1]) | (d[2]&~d[3]) | (d[0]&d[2]);
assign seg[4]= (~d[1]&~d[3]) | (d[1]&~d[2]&d[3]) | (~d[1]&d[2]) | (d[2]&~d[3]) | (d[0]&~d[3]);
assign seg[5]= (~d[2]&d[3]) | (~d[0]&d[1]) | (~d[0]&~d[2]) | (d[0]&~d[1]) | (~d[0]&d[3]);
assign seg[6]= (~d[1]&~d[2]) | (~d[0]&~d[2]&~d[3]) | (~d[0]&~d[1]) | (~d[0]&d[2]&d[3]) | (d[0]&~d[2]&d[3]) | (d[0]&d[2]&~d[3]);
assign seg[7]= (~d[1]&~d[3]) | (~d[0]&d[2]) | (d[1]&d[2]) | (~d[0]&d[1]&d[3]) | (d[0]&~d[1]&~d[2]);

endmodule
```

Testbench :

```
  `timescale 1ns/1ps
module tb_dec_7seg_selfchecking();
reg [3:0] d;
wire [7:0] seg;
dec_7seg U0(.d(d),.seg(seg));

initial begin
d=4'b0000; #10; //0000
if(seg !== 8'b11111100)$display("0 fail");
d=4'b1000; #10; //0001 
if(seg !== 8'b01100000)$display("1 fail");
d=4'b0100; #10; //0010
if(seg !== 8'b11011010)$display("2 fail");
d=4'b1100; #10; //0011
if(seg !== 8'b11110010)$display("3 fail");
d=4'b0010; #10; //0100
if(seg !== 8'b01100110)$display("4 fail");
d=4'b1010; #10; //0101
if(seg !== 8'b10110110)$display("5 fail");
d=4'b0110; #10; //0110
if(seg !== 8'b10111110)$display("6 fail");
d=4'b1110; #10; //0111
if(seg !== 8'b11100100)$display("7 fail");
d=4'b0001; #10; //1000
if(seg !== 8'b11111110)$display("8 fail");
d=4'b1001; #10; //1001
if(seg !== 8'b11100110)$display("9 fail");
d=4'b0101; #10; //1010
if(seg !== 8'b11111010)$display("a fail");
d=4'b1101; #10; //1011
if(seg !== 8'b00111110)$display("b fail");
d=4'b0011; #10; //1100
if(seg !== 8'b00011010)$display("c fail");
d=4'b1011; #10; //1101
if(seg !== 8'b01111010)$display("d fail");
d=4'b0111; #10; //1110
if(seg !== 8'b11011110)$display("e fail");
d=4'b1111; #10; //1111
if(seg !== 8'b10001110)$display("f fail");


end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not drive `seg[0]`.  An `output` port is implicitly declared as type `wire`, and `wire` types default to `z` when undriven.  To get rid of the `z`, since your testbench expects bit 0 to be 0, you could add this line inside your `dec_7seg` module:

```
assign seg[0]= 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

However, there were also other problems TT...

when i simulate modules ('dec_7seg' and 'tb_dec_7seg_selfchecking') by left clicking, every input becomes z and outputs to unknown. When i simulate by transcript using "vsim work.tb_dec_7seg_selfchecking", I could get all the right signals. 

Do you know the reason why it works that way...? 

Again, thank you so much for sparing your time.